# Json Array return null

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-5

Array in for loop returns null.

When I do this:

```
abc.a = "1";
abc.b = "1";
abc.c = "1";
```

It's all fine.
But this returns null:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  abc[i] = "1";             
}
```

The Controller Of Mvc:

```
public class abcController : Controller
{

  public ActionResult Index()
  {
    return View();
  }

  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Index(abc val)
  {
    return View();
  }
}
```

MODEL mvc abcCLASS:

```
public class abc
{
  public string a {get;set;}
  public string b { get; set; }
  public string c { get; set; }
}
```

Html + Jquery

*I want that the for will work too.*

why the in the for loop the object return null?

```
<input type="button" id="bbb"/>

<script> 
  var abc = { a: "", b: "", c: "" };
  $("#bbb").click(function () {
    // This not working:
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {      
      abc[i] = "1";             
    }
    //  This working:
    abc.a = "1";
    abc.b = "1";
    abc.c = "1";

    $.ajax({
      url: '/abc/index',
      type: "POST",
      dataType: 'json',
      traditional: true,
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      data: JSON.stringify(abc),
      success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: What makes you think `abc[0] = "1"` is identical to `abc.a = "1";`?

Comment: Please don't use quote formatting for something that isn't a quote.

Comment: How could the `for` loop possibly work - its generating an array. Your posting back to a controller method that accepts an object, not an collection!

Comment: it worked on webforms, mvc is different

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to assign some value to each element of an object. The problem is, you attempt to treat that object like an array, thinking that JS will magically understand what you want to do. It won't.

One possible way to actually do what you want:

```
for (var i in abc) if (abc.hasOwnProperty(i)) {      
  abc[i] = "1";
}
```

This way `a`, `b`, `c` properties of `abc` object will get "1" value. As it stands, you change `0`, `1`, `2` properties instead (yes, those are valid names for Object properties in JS; they're much more often used in Arrays, however).

Comment: i want to run just half of the array, i neet  i<5 ' your exmple its like foreach

Comment: Which part of your data you call an `array`?